# Display image based on response from getJSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am new to web development and I am trying to figure out how to display an image based on a response from getJSON. The data being received is from a REST API. The data is then stored in 2 arrays, humid and date. Humid contains the humidity as a string. The humid array is then converted to an Integer array- humid_final. I wanted to know how I could display a certain image on the screen based on a particular value in the humid_final array.

If the latest entry in humid_final array= 50 display image A. Else display image B. (where image A,B are static images stored locally).

```js
$(function updat() {
  var url = "https://xpm4zyor39.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/entries";
  var humid = [],
    date = [],
    humid_final = []

  $.getJSON(url, function (json) {

    $(json['Items']).each(function(i, data) {
      //Store indicator name
      
      // fill the date array
      humid.push(data.humidity);
      // fill the string data array 
      date.push(data.Date);
    });

    console.log(date);
    // query send string that we need to convert into numbers
    for (var i = 0; i < humid.length; i++) {
      if (humid[i] != null) {
        humid_final.push(parseFloat(humid[i]))
      } else {
       humid_final.push(null)
      };
    }

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
        type: 'spline',
        renderTo: 'container'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'indicatorName'
      },
      tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2,
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}%</b><br/>'
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          }
        }
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: World Bank Data'
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: date //.reverse() to have the min year on the left 
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'humidity',
        data: humid_final //
      }]
    });

  }); //getJSON method
  setTimeout(updat, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src= "opendataAPI.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. Give the image tag in your html an id and make it point to the standard image imageB like `<img id="changingImage" src="./images/imageB.png" />`

Then let's try to translate this ...

```
If the latest entry in humid_final array= 50 display image A. Else display image B.
```

into javascript:

```
if (humid_final[humid_final.length-1] == 50) {
    document.getElementById('changingImage').src="./images/imageA.png";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!